# Deleting Cerbot-issued certificate

Tags: lets-encrypt, certbot

I have a production server. I created an *exact* copy of that server for development.

```
example.com (Production Server)
dev.example.com (Development Server)
```

Because it is an exact replica, it also carried over the SSL certificates (Let's Encrypt) information from the production server.

If I delete the certificate on the development server via `sudo certbot delete`, will this affect the production server (the SSL certificate specifically) in any way? I don't completely understand SSL certificates, and I am not sure if deleting it off the server will delete it on Let's Encrypts' end or something of that sort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, It would not affect your production server anyway. The Certbot only generates and verifies that the domain belongs to you. 
Once it confirmed. Two lines are inserted into your nginx config/apache2 config.

so purging the certbot would not remove it since what your servers are using are located in `/etc/ssl/letsencrypt/....` one file ends with .pem and other .key